# Insert values alphabetically to .txt file

Tags: c#

I've an existing .txt file which is alphabetically sorted. I want to insert 3 new parameters alphabetically to the existing .txt file. Basically, the new values should get added in between so that alphabetical order of the .txt file is maintained.

Can anybody please help me? How can I go ahead with this?

Comment: Nope! You can't. Instead load the file content to `List<string>` then insert what you want and write back that `List<string>` to file.

Comment: @Alvin not sure how an array of ints would help?

Answer (score 4):

You could call this a 'merge sort' and I can quickly think of 2 ways of going about it.

1. Read your original file one line at a time, then output to a new file, adding the additional content at the correct points.
2. Read the entire file into a collection, add your new entries to the collection, ensure that the collection is sorted by some means (or use a collection type that is inherently sorted), then write the entire collection back out to a file.

What I would NOT do is try to open up space in the file and insert the new entries directly into the file.

Comment: Option 1 is probably the most efficient and scalable approach. This is, in fact, merge sort - at least its final step. The records to be inserted have to be presorted, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This probably would depend upon the size of the text file, but I would read the text file:

```
List<string> items = GetItemsFromTextFile(); //you're going to use IOStreams for this
```

Insert the new items.

```
items.add("new item 1");
items.add("new item 2");
items.add("new item 3");
```

Sort it:

```
items.Sort();
```

then write it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming performance does not really matter and you can load the file into memory you can just do the following.

```
var newLines = new [] { "new line one", "new line two", "new line three" };

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

lines = lines.Append(newLines).OrderBy(line => line).ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(filename, lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may initialize a `StreamReader` or use `File.ReadAllLines(string path, Encoding encoding)` to read the file contents into a `string` array splitted by a new line. Then, sort this array writing each `string` in the array to the file back.

**Example**

```
public static void WriteToFile(string[] linesContent, string fileLocation) //Creates a void of name WriteToFile(string[] linesContent, string fileLocation) where linesContent are the lines to write and fileLocation is the target file path to write to
{
    StreamWriter _writer = new StreamWriter(fileLocation); //Initialize a new StreamWriter of name _writer to write to fileLocation
    foreach (string s in linesContent) //Get s as a string for every string in linesContent
    {
        _writer.WriteLine(s); //Write s in a new line to the file
    }
    _writer.Close(); //Close the writer
}
public static void SortFile(string fileLocation) //Creates a void of name SortFile(string fileLocation) where fileLocation is the path of the file to sort alphabetically
{ 
    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation, Encoding.UTF8); //Initializes a string array of name Lines as the content of the file splitted by Environment.NewLine
    Array.Sort(Lines); //Sorts the string array of name Lines
    WriteToFile(Lines, fileLocation); //Writes Lines to the file
}
static void Main() //Our main entry point
{
    string fileLocation = @"D:\Resources\myfile.txt"; //Initializes a new string of name fileLocation as D:\Resources\myfile.txt
    WriteToFile(new string[] { "my third line", "this is my second line", "and this is my first line" }, fileLocation); //Writes the three lines provided to fileLocation
    SortFile(fileLocation); //Sorts fileLocation
}
```

**NOTICE**: While initializing a new `StreamWriter` of name `_writer`, we did not set `append` to `true` as we will be overwriting the file with the new sorted lines

**NOTICE**: You may use `StreamReader.ReadToEnd();` to read all the lines of the file splitting the lines by a new line and then close the `StreamReader`

**Example**

```
public static void SortFile(string fileLocation) //Creates a void of name SortFile(string fileLocation) where fileLocation is the path of the file to sort alphabetically
{ 
    StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(fileLocation); //Initializes a new StreamReader of name _reader to read from fileLocation

    string fileContents = _reader.ReadToEnd(); //Initializes a new string of name fileContents which is the file content 
    string[] Lines = fileContents.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()[0]); //Initializes a string array which is the output of splitting fileContents by a line

    Array.Sort(Lines); //Sorts the string array of name Lines
    _reader.Close(); //Closes the StreamReader so that the file can be accessible once again
    WriteToFile(Lines, fileLocation); //Writes Lines to the file
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)